# Final object rendered image is white, during render and in pose mode is normal

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders, hdri

I've only used Blender to pose objects in Blender files I have found online. I received this file from an artist who is more knowledgeable about shading and customizing. I posed it and added another object and camera but when I try to render the image with Cycles everything looks fine until the last second, the final image comes out white!

Here is the example:

While rendering:
[image: while rendering it looks fine]

Final product:
[image: final image is white/transparent!]

Any idea what could be fixed? I know he added an HDRI and did a lot with the shading.

Any way I could get this to render how it looks during the render? Here are some screenshots of what the file looks like:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey there, i highly doubt that the issue is with the shaders of the model, rather look at the world shader, i could imagine that the exposure or gamma is cranked up too high. Then there is also the "Color Management" option (all the way down in the render panel), maybe change the "Look" to "Very High Contrast". That said, it would help if you could post a picture of the world shader color management. Since i can only guess otherwise. Another part that could be responsible are posteffects or passes, as it looked like the render first comes out right and then gets white blasted.

Comment: Hello :). Since you didn't create the file, check if *Compositor* nodes are enabled. Compositing is applied on top of finished render, which fits your description of the problem.